# Constructing a Context-Free Grammar from given Language

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata

I need help with constructing a CFG for a given language.

`L = { x ∈ {a, b}* | x != x reversed }`, in other words, `L` is the complement of all the palindromes in `L`.

I'm more interested in how to approach these kind of problems rather than the specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I didn't figure the common pattern for solving such problems yet, but I think I know how to solve this problem:

First consider the CFG `G(L)` for palindrome language `L` (let's consider binary alphabet):

```
S -> ""
S -> "0" S "0"
S -> "1" S "1"
S -> "1" // odd length case
S -> "0" // odd length case
```

The idea in constructing `G(L)` is to ensure the last symbol is equal to the first symbol in S, therefore, for every position `i` the `i`th symbol from the beginning is equal to the `i`th symbol from the end for the word produced by that grammar.

For a word `w` which is not palindrome we want to ensure there is such a position `i` that the `i`th symbol from the beginning is *not* equal to the `i`th symbol from the end. So, let's terminate word production only after we have put different letters in the beginning and the end of production:

```
S -> "0" S "0"
S -> "1" S "1"
S -> "0" T "1"
S -> "1" T "0"
T -> ""
T -> "0" T "0"
T -> "1" T "1"
T -> "0" T "1" // we are allowed to put different symbols more than once
T -> "1" T "0" // we are allowed to put different symbols more than once
T -> "0"
T -> "1"
```

You can give `S` the meaning of the state «we haven't put different letters yet», and `T` the meaning of «we have put different letters». Note I've removed `S -> ""` rule in this CFG , so we will finish only from `T`, so we will definitely put different letters while producing word.